# Trigger an Outlook script after the email has entered the inbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, outlook-2010

I'm trying to finalize an integration between my access system and Outlook.

The basis of the system is that Outlook needs to trigger a script when an email enters a specific Inbox. This script then opens the Access DB and runs it's own function to go through that inbox, take the attachment in the email and import it into the database.

Currently both scripts "Work" in so far as Outlook calling Access and Access doing it's thing. The problem is when Outlook executes the script, it's BEFORE the message is actually in the mailbox. The access app will launch, scan the inbox as empty and close just before the message actually enters the inbox.

I've tried adding a "Pause" loop in the script, to try and have it wait until the email is readable before opening the access app, but that just froze outlook for the duration of the "Pause" instead of letting the email become readable.

Here is my script in Outlook:

```
Sub ExecuteDealRequest(item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim currenttime As Date

    currenttime = Now
    Do Until currenttime + TimeValue("00:00:30") <= Now
    Loop

    Dim AccessApp As Access.Application
    Set AccessApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    AccessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase ("C:\commHU\Comm HU Request.accdb"), False
    AccessApp.Visible = True
    AccessApp.DoCmd.RunMacro "Macro1"
    Set AccessApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

At this point: I'm using outlook rules to launch the script:

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
With Pricing Request in the Subject
 and on this computer only
Move it to the Pricing Requests folder
 and run Project.ExecuteDealRequest
 and stop processing more rules
```

Any help would be great, as this is the last piece that I need to get working

Comment: Maybe not an exact duplicate - this link shows how to use the 'With Events' code in Outlook:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355580/download-and-save-attachment-from-email-automatically-to-excel/37410783#37410783  Each time an email is received in a specific folder you can fire some code to process it.

Comment: I've tried adding the code to my current project but I'm having issues with the global variables and the Private WithEvents being used outside the sub (I'm still somewhat new to vb). It's saying "Only Valid in object Module"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Rule, Try it this way- code in **`ThisOutlookSession`**

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        ExecuteDealRequest Item
    End If
End Sub

' ---- Your Code
Sub ExecuteDealRequest(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim currenttime As Date
    Dim AccessApp As Access.Application
    Set AccessApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    AccessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase ("C:\commHU\Comm HU Request.accdb"), False
    AccessApp.Visible = True
    AccessApp.DoCmd.RunMacro "Macro1"
    Set AccessApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Thanks to you and Darren Bartrup-Cook I was able to do it this way, however: The same behavior was still occurring (The Macro in the Access DB would launch just before the message would update in the inbox). So I've made some fundamental changes to the code and logic where the outlook code saves the attachment into a folder and calls the access DB to process it. That way the access DB isn't waiting on the email to hit the inbox

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this,

Add this code to wait for a new email

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    ThisOutlookSession.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection).Subject
    ' Check for the email subject / any property
    'then call your method
End Sub
```

Comment: So just to clarify: I would still call the script form the rule, but this would just hold the script until the message dropped into the box?

Comment: Server-based rules versus client-only rules. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-c24f5dea-9465-4df4-ad17-a50704d66c59